# XML to HTML using XSL.Unable to read data from node

Tags: html, xml, nunit, xslt-1.0

I have a xml file with one of the nodes as:

```
<test-case time="0.077" name="TestingNunit.NUnitTestClass.NunitTestMethod1" asserts="1" success="False" result="Failure" executed="True">
  <failure>
    <message>
      <![CDATA[ Expected: not 3.0d But was: 3.0d ]]>
    </message>
    <stack-trace>
      <![CDATA[at TestingNunit.NUnitTestClass.NunitTestMethod1() in z:\UnitTestingSample\UIAutomation\TestingNunit\UnitTest1.cs:line 12 ]]>
    </stack-trace>
  </failure>
</test-case>
<test-case time="0.003" name="TestingNunit.NUnitTestClass.NunitTestMethod2" asserts="2" success="False" result="Failure" executed="True">
  <failure>
    <message>
      <![CDATA[ Expected: 2.0d But was: 3.0d ]]>
    </message>
    <stack-trace>
      <![CDATA[at TestingNunit.NUnitTestClass.NunitTestMethod2() in z:\UnitTestingSample\UIAutomation\TestingNunit\UnitTest1.cs:line 21 ]]>
    </stack-trace>
  </failure>
```

Now I want to read the data of all CDATA's". I am trying to generate a html file using XSL for which I need this data? I am able to generate data for normal nodes and their attributes but for a node written in this way I am unable to figure out a way to read it. This is my xsl file foreach loop

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
        <body>
          <table border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
              <th>Test Method</th>
              <th>Execution Time</th>
              <th>Asserts Performed</th>
              <th>Success</th>
              <th>Result</th>
              <th>Executed</th>
              <th>Failure Message</th>
              <th>Stack Trace</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="test-results/test-suite/results/test-suite/results/test-suite/results/test-case">
              <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@time"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@asserts"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@success"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@result"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@executed"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="//failure/message/text()" disable-output-escaping="no"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="//failure/stack-trace/text()" disable-output-escaping="no"/></td>
              </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </table>
        </body>
      </html>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

To read CDATAs (and then transform them) use the `text()` function in your XPath.

```
//test-case/failure/message/text()
//test-case/failure/stack-trace/text()
```

Try `select="./failure/message/text()"` instead of `select="//failure/message/text()"` (mind the `./` at the beginning).

Doing this the XPath relates to the node that is currently selected by the `for-each` loop. When using `//` it will select all nodes from the document ignoring the currently selected node. Imagine this like a `ls`command on Linux: `ls /*` will select the top level elements regardless of your current work directory, while `ls ./*` will select the child elements of your current work directory.

Comment: I am able to retrieve the data but now the problem its repeating the first CDATA for both stacktrace and message into second one also

Comment: I have added my the foreach loop from my xsl file..the problem is its reading the CDATA from the first testcase into second one also..I mean its repeating

Comment: Basically i want to read the attributes in the test-case node and the stack trace and the failure message for both the test cases..now I am able to retrieve the attributes but with CDATA I am getting the same text for both the test cases.

Comment: Expected: not 3.0d But was: 3.0d        at TestingNunit.NUnitTestClass.NunitTestMethod1() in z:\UnitTestingSample\UIAutomation\TestingNunit\UnitTest1.cs:line 12

Comment: this is getting repeated for second test case thought the data is different

Comment: It worked perfectly. Can you tell me why it was not selecting the second test case node with //?